# How to compare two lists with a third list and if a match exist group them into a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, regex, list, match, nested-lists

I have the following filenames in a list (filelist):

```
filelist = ['ABC.dat',
            'ABC3.dat',
            'ABC10.dat',
            'ABC956.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR_JKL.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR_JKL_1.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR3_JKL.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR3_JKL_1.dat',           
            'XYZ_PQR10_JKL.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR10_JKL_1.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR956_JKL.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR956_JKL_1.dat']

unique_filelist = ['ABC.dat',
                    'XYZ_PQR_JKL.dat',
                    'XYZ_PQR_JKL_1.dat',]
```

Basically a set of files are generated at different times i.e., 3, 10, 956 in this case, which I know before hand. I need to group files based on these times (fileset) that is the following nested list should be generated as output:

```
[['ABC.dat', 'ABC3.dat', 'ABC10.dat', 'ABC956.dat'],
['XYZ_PQR_JKL.dat', 'XYZ_PQR3_JKL.dat', 'XYZ_PQR10_JKL.dat', 'XYZ_PQR956_JKL.dat'],         
['XYZ_PQR_JKL_1.dat', 'XYZ_PQR3_JKL_1.dat', 'XYZ_PQR10_JKL_1.dat', 'XYZ_PQR956_JKL_1.dat']]
```

I am trying to compare the filelist with the fileset and unique_filelist and if they match add to the list. A MWE is given below, which does not do the intended:

**MWE**

```
import re
filelist = ['ABC.dat',
            'ABC3.dat',
            'ABC10.dat',
            'ABC956.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR_JKL.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR_JKL_1.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR3_JKL.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR3_JKL_1.dat',           
            'XYZ_PQR10_JKL.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR10_JKL_1.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR956_JKL.dat',
            'XYZ_PQR956_JKL_1.dat']

fileset = [3, 10, 956]

unique_filelist = ['ABC.dat',
                    'XYZ_PQR_JKL.dat',
                    'XYZ_PQR_JKL_1.dat',]

for i in filelist:
    for j in fileset:
        search_go_to = set([unique_filelist, str(j)])
        m = ' .*? '.join(x for x in search_go_to)
        matches = [s for s in filelist if re.search(m, s)]
        print (matches)
```

How to compare two lists with a third list and if a match exist group them into a nested list?

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses a little list comprehension.

I had to modify unique_filelist entries to be regexes, to show where the 'times' were inserted since it is in the middle of the basename (otherwise os.file.basename and string.startswith would have been adequate).

Also, I did not use file_set since it was not neccesary for the example data. You could add an extra filter if there were going to be 'times' in file_list which did not appear in file_set.

Finally, note there are two casts from iterators to lists, but that is just to print the result. If you were dealing with large data sets then these would best be left out, then you could iterate over 'result' in a memory efficient manner.

```
import re

file_list = ['ABC.dat',
             'ABC3.dat',
             'ABC10.dat',
             'ABC956.dat',
             'XYZ_PQR_JKL.dat',
             'XYZ_PQR_JKL_1.dat',
             'XYZ_PQR3_JKL.dat',
             'XYZ_PQR3_JKL_1.dat',
             'XYZ_PQR10_JKL.dat',
             'XYZ_PQR10_JKL_1.dat',
             'XYZ_PQR956_JKL.dat',
             'XYZ_PQR956_JKL_1.dat']

fileset = [3, 10, 956]

unique_file_list = [r'ABC\d*.dat',
                    'XYZ_PQR\d*_JKL.dat',
                    'XYZ_PQR\d*_JKL_1.dat', ]

def unique_list():
    for unique in unique_file_list:
        yield list(file for file in file_list if re.match(unique, file))

print(list(unique_list()))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, remove the '.dat' suffix from both `filelist` and `unique_filelist`

   `mod_filelist = [s[:-4] for s in filelist]
   mod_unique_filelist = [s[:-4] for s in unique_filelist]`
2. Then, split `mod_filelist` items on `_`

   `mod_filelist = [s.split('_') for s in mod_filelist]`
3. After that, remove digits succeeded by alphabetic characters

   `mod_filelist = [[re.sub(r"(\w)(\d)+", r"\1", sub_str) for sub_str in s] for s in mod_filelist]`
4. Merge the substrings of each item in the modified `filelist`

   `mod_filelist = ['_'.join(sub for sub in s) for s in mod_filelist]`
5. Create the desired nested list, with one element in each

   `result = [[unique_fname] for unique_fname in unique_filelist]`
6. Create a regex with each unique file name as a group

   `filenames_re = re.compile(r'|'.join('(' + ufname + ')' for ufname in mod_unique_filelist))`
7. Finally, fill `result` as desired

   `for i, mod_fname in enumerate(mod_filelist):
        m = re.fullmatch(filenames_re, mod_fname)
        result[m.lastindex-1].append(filelist[i])`

Hope that helps :)